# git-svn updates not visible

Tags: git, git-svn

I created a mirror of an `svn` repository via `git-svn`. The first time I did `fetch` from svn, I got revisions 1-7001, which I pushed to the github.

Now that there are 7007 revisions in svn, I did `git-svn` fetch, which appears to have downloaded the missing revisions, but:

- I can't see them in `git log` (last one is 7001)
- they don't get pushed into github when I do the standard `git push ... master`

Is there some step I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do `git-svn rebase` after your fetch to merge the changes in to your working branch.